# Why can't I pass an optional Swift String to C function that allows NULL pointers?

Tags: c, swift, macos, swift2

I have a C function that deals with C strings. The function actually allows strings to be NULL pointers. The declaration is like follows:

```
size_t embeddedSize ( const char *_Nullable string );
```

It is no problem to use this function like this in C:

```
size_t s1 = embeddedSize("Test");
size_t s2 = embeddedSize(NULL); // s2 will be 0
```

Now I'm trying to use it from Swift. The following code works

```
let s1 = embeddedSize("Test")
let s2 = embeddedSize(nil) // s2 will be 0
```

But what doesn't work is passing an optional string to it! This code will not compile:

```
let someString: String? = "Some String"
let s2 = embeddedSize(someString)
```

The compiler throws an error about the optional not being unwrapped and Xcode asks me if I maybe forgot to add `!` or `?`. However, why would I want to unwrap it? `NULL` or `nil` are valid values to be fed to the function. See above, I just passed `nil` to it directly and that compiled just well and returned the expected result. In my real code the string is fed from external and it is optional, I cannot force unwrap it, that will break if the string was `nil`. So how can I call that function with an optional string?

Comment: Your code compiles and runs with Xcode 8 beta 6.

Comment: @MartinR Yeah, this somehow sounds like a bug in the C bridging and most likely it got fixed in Swift 3. Yet I need a solution that works with Swift 2.3 :-(

Comment: @Mecki: `let s2 = someString.map { embeddedSize($0) } ?? embeddedSize(nil)` would be an option.

Answer (score 2):

The most likely answer is that while string literals are convertible to `UnsafePointer<CChar>`, and `nil` is convertible to `UnsafePointer<CChar>`, and `String` also is, `String?` might not be in Swift 2.

Comment: You analyzed the problem pretty well... but the question is, do you have a work-a-round? I tried something like `let s = (string ?? nil)` but that won't work, as of course `nil` means `nil string` and thus `s` will also be `String?` :-( I also tried `let s = (maybeString ?? UnsafePointer<UInt8>(nil))` but that won't work either as of course, what type shall `s` then be?

Comment: The best that I could come up with is this: http://iswift.org/playground?TpbkmE (EDIT: wtf, the website discarded everything between generic brackets! It should be `UnsafePointer<CChar>` and `withOptionalStringPointer<T>`.)

Comment: @zneak: Why don't you add that to your answer?

Comment: I don't think that it's particularly satisfactory. I'm not sure that I can think of anything better, though.

Answer (score 2):

In Swift 2, the C function

```
size_t embeddedSize ( const char *_Nullable string );
```

is mapped to Swift as

```
func embeddedSize(string: UnsafePointer<Int8>) -> Int
```

and you can pass a (non-optional) Swift string as the argument, 
as documented in 
[Interacting with C APIs](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/InteractingWithCAPIs.html) in the
"Using Swift with Cocoa and Objective-C" reference:

> **Constant Pointers**
>
> When a function is declared as taking a `UnsafePointer<Type>` argument, it can accept any of the following:
>
> - ...
> - A `String` value, if `Type` is `Int8` or `UInt8`. The string will automatically be converted to UTF8 in a buffer, and a pointer to that buffer is passed to the function.
> - ...

You can also pass `nil` because in Swift 2, `nil` is an allowed value
for `UnsafePointer`.

As @zneak pointed out, the "automatic conversion" to UTF-8 does not work for *optional* strings in Swift 2, so you have to (conditionally)
unwrap the string:

```
let someString: String? = "Some String"
let s2: size_t
if let str = someString {
    s2 = embeddedSize(str)
} else {
    s2 = embeddedSize(nil)
}
```

Using the `map` method of `Optional` and the nil-coalescing 
operator `??`, this can be written more compactly as

```
let someString: String? = "Some String"
let s2 = someString.map { embeddedSize($0) } ?? embeddedSize(nil)
```

One generic solution was [suggested by @zneak](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39357921/why-cant-i-pass-an-optional-swift-string-to-c-function-that-allows-null-pointer?noredirect=1#comment66046200_39357963).

Here is another possible solution. `String` has a method

```
func withCString<Result>(@noescape f: UnsafePointer<Int8> throws -> Result) rethrows -> Result
```

which calls the closure with a pointer to the UTF-8 representation
of the string, life-extended through the execution of `f`. So 
for a non-optional string, the following two statements are
equivalent:

```
let s1 = embeddedSize("Test")
let s1 = "Test".withCString { embeddedSize($0) }
```

We can define a similar method for optional strings. Since 
extensions of generic types can restrict the type placeholder only
to protocols and not to concrete types, we have to define a
protocol that `String` conforms to:

```
protocol CStringConvertible {
    func withCString<Result>(@noescape f: UnsafePointer<Int8> throws -> Result) rethrows -> Result
}

extension String: CStringConvertible { }

extension Optional where Wrapped: CStringConvertible {
    func withOptionalCString<Result>(@noescape f: UnsafePointer<Int8> -> Result) -> Result {
        if let string = self {
            return string.withCString(f)
        } else {
            return f(nil)
        }
    }
}
```

Now the above C function can be called with the optional
string argument as

```
let someString: String? = "Some String"
let s2 = someString.withOptionalCString { embeddedSize($0) }
```

For multiple C string arguments, the closure can be nested:

```
let string1: String? = "Hello"
let string2: String? = "World"

let result = string1.withOptionalCString { s1 in
    string2.withOptionalCString { s2 in
        calculateTotalLength(s1, s2)
    }
}
```

---

Apparently, the problem has been solved in Swift 3.
Here the C function is mapped to

```
func embeddedSize(_ string: UnsafePointer<Int8>?) -> Int
```

and passing a `String?` compiles and works as expected, both for
`nil` and non-`nil` arguments.

Comment: While this workaround works for `embeddedSize()`, I have other functions like that and they use multiple `const char *` arguments and if you have multiple, you'd have to make `if`s for all possible combinations, so I must find more generic way.

Comment: @Mecki: OK, I see what you mean. Did you have a look at the code that sneak  linked to in his comment? I don't know if a more elegant solution is possible, because a (optional) UTF-8 string must be generated for each Swift string, and the lifetime of that UTF-8 string must be at least until the function returns.

Comment: @Mecki: I have seen that you already figured out a solution. I have added another one (which at least resembles existing methods) to this answer.

Comment: I like your second solution more than your first one; not that   pyramiding `if` statements are particular nice if you have a lot of strings to pass to a single C function call, but they'll still look nicer than the solution I came up with; and to be honest, I had never even gotten the idea to extend the Optional type, that's pretty nifty :-)

Answer (score 1):

All the solutions that indirect the call by extra swift level, work fine if you only have one parameter. But I also have C functions like this (`strX` are not the real parameter names, the call is actually simplified):

```
size_t calculateTotalLength (
    const char *_Nullable str1,
    const char *_Nullable str2,
    const char *_Nullable str3,
    const char *_Nullable str4,
    const char *_Nullable str5
);
```

And here this indirection becomes impractical, as I need one indirection per argument, 5 indirections for the function above.

Here's the best (ugly) "hack" I came up with so far, that avoids this problem (I'm still happy to see any better solutions, maybe someone gets an idea seeing that code):

```
private
func SwiftStringToData ( string: String? ) -> NSData? {
    guard let str = string else { return nil }
    return str.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
}

let str1 = SwiftStringToData(string1)
let str2 = SwiftStringToData(string2)
let str3 = SwiftStringToData(string3)
let str4 = SwiftStringToData(string4)
let str5 = SwiftStringToData(string5)

let totalLength = calculateTotalLength(
    str1 == nil ? 
        UnsafePointer<Int8>(nil) : UnsafePointer<Int8>(str1!.bytes),
    str2 == nil ? 
        UnsafePointer<Int8>(nil) : UnsafePointer<Int8>(str2!.bytes),
    str3 == nil ? 
        UnsafePointer<Int8>(nil) : UnsafePointer<Int8>(str3!.bytes),
    str4 == nil ? 
        UnsafePointer<Int8>(nil) : UnsafePointer<Int8>(str4!.bytes),
    str5 == nil ? 
        UnsafePointer<Int8>(nil) : UnsafePointer<Int8>(str5!.bytes),
)
```

In case someone thinks about just passing the result of `data.bytes` back to the caller, this is a very bad idea! The pointer returned by `data.bytes` is only guaranteed to stay valid as long as `data` itself stays alive and ARC will kill `data` as soon as it can. So the following is not valid code:

```
// --- !!! BAD CODE, DO NOT USE !!! ---
private
func SwiftStringToData ( string: String? ) -> UnsafePointer<Int8>? {
    guard let str = string else { UnsafePointer<Int8>(nil) }
    let data = str.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
    return UnsafePointer<Int8>(data.bytes)
}
```

There is no guarantee that data is still alive when this method returns, the returned pointer might be a dangling pointer! Then I thought about the following:

```
// --- !!! BAD CODE, DO NOT USE !!! ---
private
func DataToCString ( data: NSData? ) -> UnsafePointer<Int8>? {
    guard let d = data else { UnsafePointer<Int8>(nil) }
    return UnsafePointer<Int8>(d.bytes)
}

let str1 = SwiftStringToData(string1)
let cstr1 = DataToCString(str1)
// (*1)
// ....
let totalLength = calculateTotalLength(cstr1, /* ... */)
```

But that is not guaranteed to be safe either. The compiler sees that `str1` is not referenced anymore when it gets to `(*1)`, so it may not keep it alive and when we reach the last line, `cstr1` is already a dangling pointer.

It is only safe as shown in my first sample, since there the `NSData` objects (`str1` etc.) must be kept alive to the `calculateTotalLength()` function call and some methods (like `bytes` of `NSData` or `UTF8String` of `NSString`) are tagged to return an internal pointer, in which case the compiler will make sure the lifetime of the object is extended in the current scope as long as *the object or such an internal pointer is still referenced*. This mechanism makes sure, that the returned pointers (`str1.bytes` etc.) will definitely stay valid until the C function call has returned. Without that special tagging, not even that was guaranteed! The compiler may otherwise release the `NSData` objects directly after retrieving the byte pointers but prior to making the function call, as it had no knowledge that releasing the data object makes the pointers dangling.