# Why does Swift return an unexpected pointer when converting an optional String into an UnsafePointer?

Tags: swift

I noticed some unusual behaviour when working with a C library which took strings in as `const char *` (which is converted to Swift as `UnsafePointer<Int8>!`); passing a `String` worked as expected, but a `String?` seemed to corrupt the input. Consider the test I wrote:

```
func test(_ input: UnsafePointer<UInt8>?) {
    if let string = input {
        print(string[0], string[1], string[2], string[3], string[4], string[5])
    } else {
        print("nil")
    }
}

let input: String = "Hello"

test(input)
```

This works as expected, printing a null-terminated list of UTF-8 bytes for the input string: `72 101 108 108 111 0`

However, if I change the input to an optional string, so that it becomes:

```
let input: String? = "Hello"
```

I get a completely different set of values in the result (`176 39 78 23 1 0`), even though I would expect it to be the same. Passing in `nil` works as expected.

The C library's function allows `NULL` in place of a string, and I sometimes want to pass that in in Swift as well, so it makes sense for the input string to be an optional.

Is this a bug in Swift, or was Swift not designed to handle this case? Either way, what's the best way to handle this case?

**Edit**

It appears to have something to do with multiple arguments. The C function:

```
void multiString(const char *arg0, const char *arg1, const char *arg2, const char *arg3) {
    printf("%p: %c %c %c\n", arg0, arg0[0], arg0[1], arg0[2]);
    printf("%p: %c %c %c\n", arg1, arg1[0], arg1[1], arg1[2]);
    printf("%p: %c %c %c\n", arg2, arg2[0], arg2[1], arg2[2]);
    printf("%p: %c %c %c\n", arg3, arg3[0], arg3[1], arg3[2]);
}
```

Swift:

```
let input0: String? = "Zero"
let input1: String? = "One"
let input2: String? = "Two"
let input3: String? = "Three"

multiString(input0, input1, input2, input3)
```

Results in:

```
0x101003170: T h r
0x101003170: T h r
0x101003170: T h r
0x101003170: T h r
```

It appears that there's a bug with how Swift handles multiple arguments.

Comment: Here is a (perhaps related) thread about passing optional strings to C functions, with various workarounds for Swift 2: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39357921/why-cant-i-pass-an-optional-swift-string-to-c-function-that-allows-null-pointer. However, my observation at that time was that it is no problem with Swift 3 anymore.

Comment: @MartinR: Perhaps it works when `_Nullable` is added in the C definition? I did consider that at first, but thought it was unlikely as in my test function, I used a regular optional rather than an implicitly unwrapped one, which I got when I imported the C library. Even if that's the case, I don't think it'll help because I can't modify the original library.

Comment: I just tried it with a C function taking a `const char * string` without nullable annotation, and it worked correctly in Swift 3. I *can* reproduce the problem with your test code (and the output seems to be random). That is strange and I don't have an explanation yet. I just cannot reproduce the problem with a "real" C function imported to Swift 3.

Comment: That is odd! If you're interested, the specific C function I'm having a problem with is `mysql_real_connect` from libmysqlclient.

Comment: Well, I won't install MySQL to reproduce the problem :-)  Perhaps it occurs with C functions taking multiple string parameters?

Comment: Yeah, of course! I'll see if I can run it on a function which takes just a single string...

Comment: @MartinR: I think you might be right, I've updated my question with a C test case.

Comment: Confirmed, I can reproduce that one. One can see that the *same pointer* is passed for all string arguments. You should file a bug report at https://bugs.swift.org !

Comment: [Done so](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-2814), thanks for your help! In the meantime I guess I'll just make the Swift API more restrictive to avoid the optionals in the first place, as there doesn't seem to be a good workaround.

Comment: I just upgraded to XCode 8.2.1 and the bug is still there. Do you have a bug report number? I'd like to follow Apple's comments on it.

Comment: I can also verify that if you unwrap the optionals before passing them, everything works fine.

Comment: @SteveB: https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-2814

Answer (score 1):

I didn't find anything useful on if this is desired behaviour or just a bug.

The pragmatic solution would probably be to just have a proxy method like this, but you probably did something similar already.

```
func proxy(_ str: String?, _ functionToProxy: (UnsafePointer<UInt8>?) -> ()) {
    if let str = str {
        functionToProxy(str)
    } else {
        functionToProxy(nil)
    }
}

proxy(input, test)
```

Did you test if it was working in Swift 2? They changed something maybe related in Swift 3:

https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0055-optional-unsafe-pointers.md

Comment: Yeah, I tried Swift 2.2 on IBM's Swift Sandbox, but with the same result. I can't use the proxy function because the actual C function I'm using takes in five or six string arguments, any combination of which may be optional. Instead I'm trying to extend `Optional` (when it contains a `String`) to return a correct `UnsafePointer` (though I've not been successful so far). If I get it to work and no one else has submitted a better workaround or explanation, I'll post it as answer.

Comment: Looks like a bug when there are multiple optional arguments in a C function.

Answer (score 0):

Just to be clear, there is a workaround until Apple fixes this. Unwrap your optional Strings before passing them and everything will work fine.

```
var anOptional: String?
var anotherOptional: String?

func mySwiftFunc() {

    let unwrappedA = anOptional!
    let unwrappedB = anotherOptional!

    myCStringFunc(unwrappedA, unwrappedB)

}
```

Comment: This doesn't actually work for my case, as I want to pass NULL into the C function if the optional String is nil (your answer would presumably cause a crash). Although I've not tested it, making a C function (in this case called `unwrap`) which simply takes an input string and returns it, and wrapping each argument in that, would probably work, looking something like: `test_c_function(unwrap(optionalString1), unwrap(optionalString2), unwrap(optionalString3))`

Comment: You could use the coalescing operator and check for an empty string instead of a null in your C function. That wouldn't work if an empty string was ever a valid input, though.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, this is a clear bug in Swift.

Here's a workaround I'm using. If you can't trust Swift to convert the strings to pointers for you, then you've got to do it yourself.

Assuming C function defined as:

```
void multiString(const char *arg0, const char *arg1, const char *arg2);
```

Swift code:

```
func callCFunction(arg0: String?, arg1: String?, arg2: String?) {
    let dArg0 = arg0?.data(using: .utf8) as NSData?
    let pArg0 = dArg0?.bytes.assumingMemoryBound(to: Int8.self)

    let dArg1 = arg1?.data(using: .utf8) as NSData?
    let pArg1 = dArg1?.bytes.assumingMemoryBound(to: Int8.self)

    let dArg2 = arg2?.data(using: .utf8) as NSData?
    let pArg2 = dArg2?.bytes.assumingMemoryBound(to: Int8.self)

    multiString(pArg1, pArg2, pArg3)
}
```

**Warning:**

Don't be tempted to put this in a function like:

```
/* DO NOT USE -- BAD CODE */
func ocstr(_ str: String?) -> UnsafePointer<Int8>? {
    guard let str = str else {
        return nil
    }

    let nsd = str.data(using: .utf8)! as NSData

    //This pointer is invalid on return:
    return nsd.bytes.assumingMemoryBound(to: Int8.self)
}
```

which would remove repeated code. This doesn't work because the data object `nsd` gets deallocated at the end of the function. The pointer is therefore not valid on return.