# Swift getaddrinfo

Tags: swift, memory, posix, low-level-api

POSIX `getaddrinfo` allocates memory that must later be freed using `freeaddrinfo`.
See http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man3/getaddrinfo.3.html

To simplify the API, I've created this function:

```
import Foundation

enum SystemError: Swift.Error {
    case getaddrinfo(Int32, Int32?)
}

public func getaddrinfo(node: String?, service: String?, hints: addrinfo?) throws -> [addrinfo] {
    var err: Int32
    var res: UnsafeMutablePointer<addrinfo>?
    if var hints = hints {
        err = getaddrinfo(node, service, &hints, &res)
    } else {
        err = getaddrinfo(node, service, nil, &res)
    }
    if err == EAI_SYSTEM {
        throw SystemError.getaddrinfo(err, errno)
    }
    if err != 0 {
        throw SystemError.getaddrinfo(err, nil)
    }
    defer {
        freeaddrinfo(res)
    }
    var result = [addrinfo]()
    var ai = res?.pointee
    while ai != nil {
        result.append(ai!)
        ai = ai!.ai_next?.pointee
    }
    return result
}
```

I don't feel that the function is correct, though.

- How can the Swift memory model know that `getaddrinfo` allocates memory, and that Swift should not overwrite that memory with own stuff?
- How can Swift know that `freeaddrinfo` deletes the whole list, and that it should copy out ai information that has been assigned to the result array?

What's the correct way to interface with `getaddrinfo`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Memory allocated by `getaddrinfo` (e.g. by `malloc`) will not be given to any other
dynamic memory allocation function in the same running process
until released by `freeaddrinfo` (e.g. by `free`).
Therefore the Swift runtime will not trample on that memory (if we
assume that it has no programming errors such as wrong pointer calculations).

Also `struct addrinfo` is a value type, so

```
result.append(ai!)
```

will append a copy of the pointed-to structure to the array.

*But there is still a problem.* Some members of `struct addrinfo`
are pointers

```
public var ai_canonname: UnsafeMutablePointer<Int8>! /* canonical name for hostname */
public var ai_addr: UnsafeMutablePointer<sockaddr>! /* binary address */
```

which may point into the memory allocated by `getaddrinfo` and therefore
invalid after `freeaddrinfo`, and dereferencing them after your
function returns causes undefined behaviour.

Therefore you must either postpone the `freeaddrinfo` until the
address list is not needed anymore, or copy the information.
This is a bit cumbersome because `ai_addr` may point to a 
IPv4 or IPv6 socket address structure which have different length.

The following code demonstrates how the address list can be copied
to an array of `sockaddr_storage` structures (which are large enough
to hold any IP address). This code has not been thoroughly tested,
so use it with care.

```
public func getaddrinfo(node: String, service: String, hints: addrinfo?) throws -> [sockaddr_storage] {
    var err: Int32
    var res: UnsafeMutablePointer<addrinfo>?
    if var hints = hints {
        err = getaddrinfo(node, service, &hints, &res)
    } else {
        err = getaddrinfo(node, service, nil, &res)
    }
    if err == EAI_SYSTEM {
        throw SystemError.getaddrinfo(err, errno)
    }
    if err != 0 {
        throw SystemError.getaddrinfo(err, nil)
    }
    defer {
        freeaddrinfo(res)
    }
    guard let firstAddr = res else {
        return []
    }

    var result = [sockaddr_storage]()
    for addr in sequence(first: firstAddr, next: { $0.pointee.ai_next }) {
        var sockAddr = sockaddr_storage()
        memcpy(&sockAddr, addr.pointee.ai_addr, Int(addr.pointee.ai_addrlen))
        result.append(sockAddr)
    }
    return result
}
```

Remarks:

- If you are only interested in a single address family then
  you can replace `sockaddr_storage` by `sockaddr_in` or
  `sockaddr_in6`.
- I have made the `node` and `service` parameters non-optional.
  The reason is that Swift currently has a Bug when passing more 
  than one optional String to a C function, see
  [Why does Swift return an unexpected pointer when converting an optional String into an UnsafePointer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39806995/why-does-swift-return-an-unexpected-pointer-when-converting-an-optional-string-i).
- `sequence()` is used here to traverse the linked list instead of
  a `while` loop.

Comment: This is tangential to your answer, but: where did you get the Swift versions of the `addrinfo` fields? Did you just rewrite them by hand, or is there a tool that displays the Swift interface to C code? (I am dealing with C in Swift this week and would love to know.)

Comment: @JoshCaswell: I am not sure if I understand your question. Command-click on `addrinfo` displays the header as it is imported to Swift. – You can also add `#import <netdb.h>` to any C file, command-click on "netdb.h" to jump to that file, and then choose "Generated Interface".

Comment: "Generated interface" in Xcode is the piece I was missing, thank you!

Comment: Even though in theory, value types should be copied, can't the compiler optimization mess this up? e.g. copy-on-write etc.

Comment: @Etan: Swift uses cow for the *backing store* of e.g. strings and arrays, i.e. only for types that it knows and manages. `struct addrinfo` is imported from C and Swift won't mess with it.

Comment: Thanks for that info, makes sense! However, is there any official source to read about Swift's memory model, or is this just insider knowledge?

Comment: @Etan: Unfortunately I do not have *the* reference but here are some pointers: https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/array mentions copy-on-write, https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/docs/Arrays.rst and  https://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2015-04-17-lets-build-swiftarray.html  show how arrays are implemented. Joe Groff states at https://lists.swift.org/pipermail/swift-users/Week-of-Mon-20160516/001980.html that Swift respects the layout of imported structures.

Comment: Thanks for the resources! I've revised the function and put it up here: http://pastebin.com/y7nDATSH – in the end, I went with the linked list to mimic the original behaviour as close as possible.