# Swift Sqlite SQL error

Tags: swift, sqlite

I'm attempting to create a simple sqlite database in Swift, but I'm getting an error (specifically SQLITE_ERROR) when attempting to create a table.

Here is my code:

```
        var db :OpaquePointer?
        let dbPath = try FileManager.default.url(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: false)
            .appendingPathComponent("\(Date.init().timeIntervalSince1970)".replacingOccurrences(of: ".", with: "") + ".db")
            .absoluteString

        var returnCode :Int32 = sqlite3_open(dbPath.cString(using: .utf8), &db)
        if SQLITE_OK != returnCode {
            preconditionFailure("Failed to open db")
        }

        var stmt :OpaquePointer?
        returnCode = sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, "CREATE TABLE Things (name TEXT)".cString(using: .utf8), -1, &stmt, nil)
        if SQLITE_OK != returnCode {
            preconditionFailure("Failed to prepare table creation SQL")
        }
```

Sqlite is included via a Cocoapod. I have tried using different encodings of the string when converting to a C string, specifically I've tried using ASCII encoding, and I've also tried hard coding the database name.

The error occurs in `sqlite3_prepare_v2`.

The error message is "near \"\u{01}\": syntax error"

Comment: Use `sqlite3_errmsg()` to print the error reason. – Note that you can pass a Swift String directly to C functions, e.g.  `sqlite3_open(dbPath, &db)`

Comment: @MartinR The error message is "near \"\u{01}\": syntax error"

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34135305/nsfilemanager-defaultmanager-fileexistsatpath-returns-false-instead-of-true ? –  Don't use `absoluteString` to get a file path.

Comment: @MartinR I've changed my code to use `path` instead of `absoluteString` and it still fails at the same point. The error message changes though, to "near \""

Comment: Have you tried to remove the unnecessary `.cString(using: .utf8)` stuff?

Comment: @MartinR Looks like that was the cause, thanks! Post as an answer and I'll accept.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not 100% sure *why* your `.cString(using: .utf8)` approach
to convert a Swift string to a C string causes problems.
It could be the same issue as in
[Why does Swift return an unexpected pointer when converting an optional String into an UnsafePointer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39806995/why-does-swift-return-an-unexpected-pointer-when-converting-an-optional-string-i) (which was
reported as a Swift bug). Unwrapping the result of `cString()`
explicitly seems to help:

```
let sql = "CREATE TABLE Things (name TEXT)".cString(using: .utf8)!
returnCode = sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, sql, -1, &stmt, nil)
```

But you can pass a Swift `String` directly to C functions expecting
a `const char *` (compare [String value to UnsafePointer<UInt8> function parameter behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27063569/string-value-to-unsafepointeruint8-function-parameter-behavior)):

```
var returnCode = sqlite3_open(dbPath, &db)
// ...
returnCode = sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, "CREATE TABLE Things (name TEXT)", -1, &stmt, nil)
```

and this works as expected.

Additional remarks:

- Use `.path` to convert a `URL` to a file path string,
  not `.absoluteString`.
- Use `sqlite3_errmsg()` to get error messages if something failed.
- Remove unnecessary type annotations, as in `var returnCode :Int32`.

Putting it all together:

```
var db: OpaquePointer?
let dbPath = try FileManager.default.url(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: false)
    .appendingPathComponent("xxx.db")
    .path

var returnCode = sqlite3_open(dbPath, &db)
if SQLITE_OK != returnCode {
    let errmsg = String(cString: sqlite3_errmsg(db))
    fatalError("Failed to open db: \(errmsg)")
}

var stmt: OpaquePointer?
returnCode = sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, "CREATE TABLE Things (name TEXT)", -1, &stmt, nil)
if SQLITE_OK != returnCode {
    let errmsg = String(cString: sqlite3_errmsg(db))
    fatalError("Failed to prepare table creation SQL: \(errmsg)")
}
```